# MySQL InnoDB auto increment column based on combination of other columns

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am making a system where users can upload any file they want, and not use it to execute any kind of code. As a part of that, I rename every file, and store its original name in a MySQL table. This table contains the id of the user who uploaded it, and a unique id of the upload. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `upload_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `original_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `mime_type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `upload_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This means I will always have a unique combination of user_id and upload_id, and every users first upload has an id of 1. However I heard MyISAM is old, and i should rather use InnoDB.
Is there any way I can achieve this in InnoDB?

Comment: Why do you have `user_id` as primary key? and are you getting any error when you use innoDB?

Comment: @meLove i want upload_id to autoincrement for each user_id. The only way i was able to find, was the one i'm using, described here: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) However that one clearly specifies it needs to use MyISAM or BDB.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know what the actual problem with MyISAM was, and if it's just this, it will be fine.

Comment: You can definitely use autoincrement id in InnoDB as you can in myISAM - the major benefit of InnoDB is that you can use foreign keys. But to achieve what you want, and if I understood correctly, the upload_id MUST be 1 for the FIRST upload per user then an autoincrement id is not the way forward because I believe an autoincrement id MUST be the primary key and thus you cannot have a value repeated. I would use a standard int field and write a stored procedure to do the calculations for that value

Comment: @Jaydee could you write your comment as an answer? i cannot accept it otherwise

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb for how to simulate that PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem with MyISAM tables is that they are not transactional. From what you say, you will only be creating records and then reading them (possibly deleting them later) but there will be little or no editing. This situation is what MyISAM was designed for, it is fast for mostly read only records. Personally I see no advantage converting to InnoDB.